# Java Merge Big List

Tags: java, arraylist, merge

I have two ArrayList that I receive after making my DB query , the result of the query will return a lot of elements ( > 500.000 elements) . I need to make a merge between the results for the union of two lists to create a java object. The problem is, how It could make the merge between the two list efficiently from two different Database? Result Lists like this:

**List A**

```
Id1, Name1, Description1
Id2, Name2, Description2
Id3, Name3, Description3
```

**List B**

```
Id1, Position1
Id2, Position2
Id3, Position3
```

**Result**

```
Id1, Name1, Description1, Position1
Id2, Name2, Description2, Position2
Id3, Name3, Description3, Position3
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is a "BBDD query"? If you mean a query from a database, then you should let the database do the work; rewrite your SQL query so that the database returns the result you need, instead of doing two queries and do the join in your own program.

Comment: BBDD query - probably the parkinson version of DB query

Comment: Sorry, I do two different queries to two different databases: list A - > DB A and listB -> DB B

Answer (score 0):

If the below conditions are true:

1. ArrayLists hold comma separated String Objects
2. The Id field occurs first in the second list and doesn't contain comma character
3. The count and sequence of items in both the list are the same

Then the following code should do the merge.

```
ArrayList<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();
listA.add("Id1, Name1, Description1");
listA.add("Id2, Name2, Description2");
listA.add("Id3, Name3, Description3");

ArrayList<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>();
listB.add("Id1, Position1");
listB.add("Id2, Position2");
listB.add("Id3, Position3");

ArrayList<String> mergedList = new ArrayList<String>();
Integer index=-1;
for(String listAEntry : listA){
    index++;
    mergedList.add(listAEntry.concat(listB.get(index).replaceFirst(".*,", ",")));
}
```

Here's the contents of merged list:

```
Id1, Name1, Description1, Position1
Id2, Name2, Description2, Position2
Id3, Name3, Description3, Position3
```